Can saying “I know” sometimes be a rude response?
Is “I know” rude sometimes?
My friend’s at an airport waiting to board a plane. Maybe the airline overbooked its tickets; most people have boarded the plane, but he and maybe two other people still weren’t called in. My friend told the attendant at the gate (where he’s supposed to board the plane) that he still didn’t have a boarding pass. The attendant yelled “I know.”
I wonder whether responding with “I know” is ever a rude thing to say. In my native language, it can sometimes be rude, implying that what the other person has just said is superfluous and unnecessary.

I’m voting to close this question because the attendant was rude, possibly justified, but not in word choice. "Yes, I am so sorry, and will get to you right away" can be rude in its tone.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
